# Flutter ListTile onTap function doesn't redirect to new page

Tags: flutter

I made a list tile but the `onTap` function doesn't redirect to new dart page. It worked in my previous program but it doesn't right now. Can you put me on the right path I don't understand what is wrong with my code. I just want that when user clicks to tile it redirects to the relevant or assigned dart file. For example: Kargo should redirect to kargo.dart.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'kargo.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Akçakale Sarı Sayfa',
      theme: ThemeData(
        visualDensity: VisualDensity.adaptivePlatformDensity,
      ),
      home: MyHomePage(title: 'Akçakale Sarı Sayfa'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);

  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text(widget.title,
            style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amberAccent, fontSize: 24)),
        backgroundColor: Colors.black87,
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.vertical(
            bottom: Radius.circular(20),
          ),
        ),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Column(
          mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
          children: <Widget>[
            Card(
              child: ListTile(
                  leading: const Icon(
                    Icons.directions_bus,
                    color: Colors.white,
                  ),
                  title: Text(
                    'Kargo',
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.amberAccent),
                  ),
                  tileColor: Colors.black87,
                  onTap: () {
                    Navigator.push(context,
                        new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new kargo()));
                  }),
            ),
```

Comment: are you getting any error? If no, please share code for `Kargo`.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you I solved the error. I just assigned Kargo to new page as class